# bash pipe inside loop vs piping after loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, pipe, netcat

I'm doing some challenge online. The lvl asked us to do some brute forcing.

SO now what's the difference between this 2 solutions :

```sh
## Solution 1
for i in $(seq -w 9999); do 
  echo "password_previous_lvl $i" 
done | nc localhost 30002

## Solution 2
for i in $(seq -w 9999); do 
  echo "password_previous_lvl $i" | nc localhost 30002
done
```

The only things that is changing here is the piping.

I try to execute just the command in the shell. The output is :

```
bandit24@bandit:~$ echo "password_previous_lvl 2525" | nc localhost 30002
I am the pincode checker for user bandit25. Please enter the password for user bandit24 and the secret pincode on a single line, separated by a space.
Wrong! Please enter the correct pincode. Try again.

Timeout. Exiting.
```

There is a timeout.

If I try again directly in the shell with an other password the output is :

```
bandit24@bandit:~$ echo "password_previous_lvl 2525" | nc localhost 30002
I am the pincode checker for user bandit25. Please enter the password for user bandit24 and the secret pincode on a single line, separated by a space.
Wrong! Please enter the correct pincode. Try again.
password_previous_lvl 2526
Timeout. Exiting.
```

Just the timeout at then end just like before and no error message.

So I don't understand why when I use the solution number 1 with the piping at the end of the loop I got this result properly :

```sh
bandit24@bandit:/tmp$ ./b.sh
I am the pincode checker for user bandit25. Please enter the password for user bandit24 and the secret pincode on a single line, separated by a space.
Wrong! Please enter the correct pincode. Try again.
Wrong! Please enter the correct pincode. Try again.
......
Wrong! Please enter the correct pincode. Try again.
Correct!
The password of user bandit25 is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Exiting.
```

Can someone explaining me the why ?

Another question is : Why does it ends when the good pin has been found and does not continue ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: In the first solution you are opening the connection only once and sending the echo statement 9999 times. In the second, you set up the connection 9999 times and then send the echo statement once for each connection.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Why comment and not answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment @Raman Sailopal

`In the first solution you are opening the connection only once and sending the echo statement 9999 times. In the second, you set up the connection 9999 times and then send the echo statement once for each connection.`